# Is it possible to turn this into a (standard) integer convex knapsack problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have found a solution algorithm for integer knapsack problems of the following form:

> $\max\limits_{x_j \in [l_j,u_j]} \sum_{j=1}^n f_j(x_j)$
>         such that $\sum_{j=1}^n g_j(x_j) \leq b$
>   Where $l_j<u_j$ and $f_j$ are concave and $g_j$ are convex on $[l_j,u_j]$, and both $f_j$ and $g_j$ are monotonically increasing on $[l_j,u_j]$.

I have a problem of the following form and im trying to write it in the above form but im not sure its possible:

> $\min\limits_{x_j \in [l_j,u_j]} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j c_j$
>   such that $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{x_j^{p-1}}d_j \leq b$
>   Where $p\in (1,2]$ and $c_j, d_j$ are known positive constants.

I could turn the $\min x_jc_j$ into a $\max f_j$ by defining $f_j(x_j) = -c_jx_j$ and it would be concave but the problem is the monotonicity. I cant introduce a subsitution $y_j=-x_j$ because thats not defined for the $g_j$. Is there maybe another approach?

Comment: I do not see why the substitution causes a problem for $g$.

Comment: it seems like i made some errors posing the question I corrected them, sorry. The $x_i$ have to be integer and $g_j$ are decreasing if $x_j$ is increasing, that should be the other way around in the "standard" form

Comment: did I  rephrase the problem correctly?

Comment: no, in the first form the $f_j$ and $g_j$ are both increasing functions on $[l_j,u_j]$. in my given problem (the 2nd one) the $g_j$ are decreasing. Hence my question if it is possible, to transform the 2nd one into the form of the 1st one.
Now its correct, thank you.

Comment: After the substitution $y_j = -x_j$, $g(x) = d_j / (-y_j)^{p-1}$ satisfies the conditions, right? Assuming $l_j >0$.

Comment: I think you are right. Im afraid I made an error with the substitution. Lets assume n=1 and $c_1=d_1=1$,$p=2$, and $l_1=1,u_1=10$. So we have the problem $\min\limits_{x \in [1,10]\cap \mathbb{Z}}$ $x$, such that $\frac{1}{x} \leq b$. So we get $\max\limits_{x \in [1,10]\cap \mathbb{Z}}$ $-x$, such that $\frac{1}{x} \leq b$. If we now let y:=-x, we have the problem $\max\limits_{y \in [-10,-1]\cap \mathbb{Z}}$ $-(-y)$, such that $\frac{1}{-y} \leq b$. Now both $f_1$ and $g_1$ are monotone increasing on $[-u_1,-l_1]$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Great, thank you for your help and time, I really appreciate it.